# Distribute population to health facilities (GP Practices)

Tags: buffer, population, distribution, health

I have been using GIS (ArcGis) for some years but I do not consider myself an expert.

I am performing some analysis around GP Practices in London (UK), I would like to be able to estimate the catchment area of each practice, so that in case a new development is built I can estimate if the new incoming population will have an impact on the existing GPs.

The datasets (shapefiles) I have are the following:

- Population (by super output areas / wards / etc..)
- Postcodes (OS Code-Point Open - centroid of the postcode area)
- GP Practices (as points - database information is inclusive of number
  of registered patients and number of General Practitioners)

I don't think performing a buffer would be the right think to do as many GP Practices share the same building or are very close one to each other, therefore the buffers will overlap and I will have the problem of distributing the population equally among all the different buffers.

Every GP Practice has its own number of registered patients, therefore I believe calibrating the extent of the buffer according to the actual patient list size would be the right approach but I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone have any suggestion?